# useEffect not triggering but the template is being rendered somehow

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting too many re-renders while using react-hooks.
I am trying to fetch data from api by using a parameter in URL.
Here's the code:

```
export default function Details() {
  const { title } = useParams();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  function getDetails(keyword) {
    if (keyword) {
      setLoading(true);
      fetch(
        `API`
      )
        .then((res) => {
          let result = res.data.results;
          result = result.filter(function (result) {
            return (result.title = keyword);
          });
          setDetails(result[0]);
          setLoading(false);
          console.log(details);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(["Unable to fetch data"]);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }

  getDetails(title)
  return(
     // template
)
```

now I think this is happening at the line where I call getDetails.
then I tried using useEffect to load the data only once after it is mounted,

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDetails(title);
  }, []);
```

It still is unable to fetch the data, as the getDetails function is never called.
How can I resolve this?
Edit:
Fixed one silly error.
Here's the codesandbox link:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-franklin-pcz9v)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with this, first you need to specify what you want to be notified about when the useEffect gets called again. You could do this by adding the variables you want within the array

```
      useEffect(() => {
            getDetails(title);
          }, [ 
                // Add what you want here 
    ]);
```

The second issue you have is that you declared the detalis variable twice. Once using the set state here:   `const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);`

The second time here:

```
const details = getDetails(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your getDetails function has title param so I would add `title and getDetails` both in the dependency list of `useEffects`

Or place `getDetails` inside the useEffect

Here is your working code. You had multiple problems where `res.data` was undefined so you need to get `res.results` directly based on your response object

```
useEffect(() => {
    function getDetails(keyword) {
      if (keyword) {
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(
          `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=${keyword}&page=1&genre_exclude=0`
        )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.results);
            let result = res.results;
            console.log(result);
            result = result.filter(function (result) {
              return (result.title = keyword);
            });
            
            setDetails(result[0]);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(3);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            setError(["Unable to fetch data"]);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      }
    }
    console.log('calling getDetails')
    getDetails(title);
  }, [title]);
```

Note: tested in the code sandbox link provided in the question. Its working code.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I had to get the definition inside the useEffect but still function does not work.
The thing is title is taken from parameter which is constant. Do you think that might be causing it to not work?

Comment: If you provide codesandbox link with this sample code really help.

Comment: I am able to resolve and see the details on UI with above code.

Comment: Try clicking on one of the anime results. That's where the issue is.

Comment: Yes, clicked on it and details are shown in the UI. You can replace your useEffects from above code and test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228036/discussion-between-pavan-and-abhishek-ghadge).

Answer (score 0):

the code here has two obvious error beside the functionality problems you mentioned:

1 - you cannot declare two variables with same name using `let` or `const`; it will throw a `SyntaxError`

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  ...
const details = getDetails(title)
```

2- `getDetails` function is written with a asynchronous mindset, and it will return nothing,

so `details` in `const details = getDetails(title)` will be set to `undefined`

Comment: I cleared the first error. But how should I approach the error two?
I tried using async await in getDetails but still it does not work.